# Serializing data created by ATTiny85 for use on PC

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny

Have an AES-128 implementation I'd like to install on an ATTiny85 for embedded use but need to come up with a way to **communicate with it from a PC** as you would do via Serial on Arduino Uno. For example, I'd like to stream 16 bytes of plaintext and get back 16 bytes of ciphertext (or signature hash, etc.).

The faster the transfer rate, the better obviously, but it would of course need to fit on the remaining space on an ATTiny85.

Any thoughts or working examples out there (i.e. I2C for PC, etc.) without incurring a lot of extra hardware cost?

Comment: Is there any reason why V-USB isn't an option?

Comment: Haven't looked into V-USB yet. If it fits, I'm fine with that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So is this what we're talking about? http://codeandlife.com/2012/02/22/v-usb-with-attiny45-attiny85-without-a-crystal/

Comment: That article is badly out of date, but yes.

Comment: It might seem a little old fashioned, but a software implementation of an RS-232 type link could work for you. It might be easier than V-USB and require less resources on the AVR. I think that's the way I would go.  Regards,

Comment: The problem with using RS-232 with the ATtiny85 is that the '85 doesn't have a hardware UART. Its USI can be used to emulate one, but only in half duplex.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not up on my baud rates and hardware but what would that be equivalent of in units of bits per second? How fast could I shove 16 bytes to the ATTiny85 and back?

Comment: I think half duplex would work in this application.  A 16 char string comes in, gets processed, then a 16 byte string goes out.  Remember the V-USB has to send data, RS-232 can do it at the same rate, it seems to me.  Looking around the 'net it seems that LadyAda coded a interrupt driven software serial port which is now included in the base code for Arduino.  Here is a bit of a write-up:  http://arduiniana.org/libraries/newsoftserial/

Comment: Or you could use [this](https://github.com/frank26080115/Arduino-UsiSerial-Library).

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' tip, it looks like I'll be able to accomplish this with [V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html):

> V-USB is a software-only implementation of a low-speed USB device for
>   Atmel’s AVR® microcontrollers, making it possible to build USB
>   hardware with almost any AVR® microcontroller, not requiring any
>   additional chip.

**Requirements:** AVR microcontroller with at least 2 kB of Flash memory, 128 bytes RAM and a clock rate of at least 12 MHz.

Taken from [ATTiny85's Datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2586-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny25-attiny45-attiny85_datasheet.pdf):

> - 8K Bytes of In-System Programmable Program Memory Flash
> - 512 Bytes In-System Programmable EEPROM (enough for third-two 16-byte keys)
> - 512 Bytes Internal SRAM

Looking forward to trying it out :)

Comment: Keep us updated on how it works out, please. Regards,

Comment: Haven't had a chance to implement this yet, but I might also look at your RS-232 recommendation. Ah, reminds me of my very first electronics project: [the $4.00 serial link](http://www.ticalc.org/hardware/cables/serial.html) for my Ti-83+.

Answer (score 0):

> Any thoughts or working examples out there (i.e. I2C for PC, etc.) without incurring a lot of extra hardware cost?

Yet another alternative is to use the Display Data Channel (DDC) on the PC. This is 5V and I2C. Unfortunately not all PC video boards support I2C. Please see the [reference](http://www.instructables.com/id/Worlds-Cheapest-I2C-I-Squared-C-Adapter/?ALLSTEPS) for further details.

I2C is supported on ATtiny by the USI module.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> need to come up with a way to communicate with it from a PC

would be difficult to make an uart out of usi?